# Request limit for content works in local machine but not working after deployment to azure

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have requirement to upload image 20mb to azure storage. For that i had exposed a API Controller which will receive image as base64 string. I had set maxallowedcontentlength to 20 mb in web.config. It works fine in local machine once i push to azure then test the mobile services it not working as expected throwing model entity error. Below in the config changes i used

```
  <system.web>

       <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="9000" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="20000000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>

  </system.webServer>
```

Could you please give me some solution to fix the issue.

Regards

Endeavour

Comment: what is the model entity error? are you able to add it here?

Comment: Also, just to confirm - this is an ASP.NET app? or is it a Node.js app?

Comment: ASP.NET APP. Got fix from microsoft team.